# Somando atributos de um Objeto List

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho uma lista de vendas com os atributos (id, valor, dataCompra, finalizadora).
Na minha classe Vendas tenho um método que recebe o mês e o ano e através desses argumentos deve retornar a soma total das vendas do período solicitado.
**Porem não estou sabendo como fazer pra pegar apenas o atributo "valor" e somar todos eles.**

segue abaixo o que já fiz.

```
public class Venda {

    private Integer id; 
    private Double valor;
    private Date dataCompra;
    private Finalizadora tipoCompra; 
    
    private List<Venda> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    
    public Venda () {
        
    }

    public Venda(Integer id, Double valor, Date dataCompra, Finalizadora tipoCompra) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.dataCompra = dataCompra;
        this.tipoCompra = tipoCompra;
    }
    
    public Double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public Date getDataCompra() {
        return dataCompra;
    }

    public void setDataCompra(Date dataCompra) {
        this.dataCompra = dataCompra;
    }

    public Finalizadora getTipoCompra() {
        return tipoCompra;
    }

    public void setTipoCompra(Finalizadora tipoCompra) {
        this.tipoCompra = tipoCompra;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void addVenda(Venda venda) {
        list.add(venda);
    }
    
    public void removeVenda(Venda venda) {
        list.remove(venda);
    }
    
    public double somaValor() {
        double sum = 0;
         sum += valor;
          return sum;
    }
    
    
    public Status verStatus(Date dataCompra) {
        long diff = new Date().getTime() - dataCompra.getTime();
        diff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Status st;
        if(diff <= 30) {
             st = Status.ATIVO;
        }
        else if (diff >= 31 && diff <= 90) {
            st = Status.PRE_INATIVO;
        }
        else {
            st = Status.INATIVO;
        }
        
        return st;
        
    }
    
    public void escolhaData(int mesEsc, int anoEsc ) {
        int dia, mes, ano;
        double sum = 0;
    
        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendario.setTime(getDataCompra());
        dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        mes = 1 + calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        
        if(mesEsc == mes && anoEsc == ano ) {
            for(Venda v : list) {
                sum = v.somaValor();
            }
            
            System.out.println(sum);
            }
        
        
        }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dados da Venda \n" +  
                " valor:  " + valor + 
                ", Data:  " + sdf.format(dataCompra) + 
                ", Forma de pagamento: " + tipoCompra;
    }
    
    
}
```

Classe main com a inserção na lista.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        List<Venda> listVed = new ArrayList<>();
        listVed.add(new Venda(1,400.0,sdf.parse("11/04/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(2,900.0,sdf.parse("11/04/2022"),Finalizadora.Dinheiro));
        listVed.add(new Venda(3,1400.0,sdf.parse("21/04/2022"),Finalizadora.Pix));
        listVed.add(new Venda(4,1200.0,sdf.parse("30/05/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(5,9000.0,sdf.parse("20/05/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(6,3500.0,sdf.parse("01/05/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(7,1200.0,sdf.parse("30/05/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(8,1346.0,sdf.parse("02/06/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(9,1500.0,sdf.parse("29/06/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(10,1200.0,sdf.parse("30/06/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(11,700.0,sdf.parse("30/06/2021"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(11,1000.0,sdf.parse("30/06/2021"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        
        System.out.println("Escolha o mês (somente numeros): ");
        int mesEsc = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Escolha o ano (somente numeros): ");
        int anoEsc = sc.nextInt();  
        for(Venda v : listVed) {
            v.escolhaData(mesEsc , anoEsc); 
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você esta misturando regras de negócio com objetos de modelo no seu código. Tente separar essa busca por datas para uma função fora da classe que vc armazena os dados da venda.

Comment: Olá amigo. Sim entendi seu ponto, e pretendo fazer a separação das regras de negocio dos objetos. Mas antes de fazer isso quero testar e ver se está tudo funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma pequena confusão no seu código.

Na sua classe `Venda` você tem uma propriedade `list`que é uma lista de objetos da classe `Venda`. E a função que `escolhaData` que é a função que percorre a lista de vendas e soma seus valores faz isso utilizando a propriedade `list` que esta contida dentro da classe venda.

Veja que em nenhum momento você popula essa lista de vendas contida dentro da classe `Venda`. Em vez disso você cria uma outra lista na sua classe `main` onde é populada outra lista de venda com os objetos com valores. veja que em nenhum momento você populou qualquer lista contida dentro do objeto `Venda`.

Sendo assim minha dica pra você é manter na classe venda apenas informações relacionadas a venda como valor, data, etc. E na sua main você ter as funções para manipular esses objetos e uma lista deles como adicionar, remover, somar valores etc. Logo seu código ficaria +/- assim.

```java
public class Main {
    private static List<Venda> vendas = new ArrayList<Venda>()
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        List<Venda> listVed = new ArrayList<>();
        listVed.add(new Venda(1,400.0,sdf.parse("11/04/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(2,900.0,sdf.parse("11/04/2022"),Finalizadora.Dinheiro));
        listVed.add(new Venda(3,1400.0,sdf.parse("21/04/2022"),Finalizadora.Pix));
        listVed.add(new Venda(4,1200.0,sdf.parse("30/05/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(5,9000.0,sdf.parse("20/05/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(6,3500.0,sdf.parse("01/05/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(7,1200.0,sdf.parse("30/05/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(8,1346.0,sdf.parse("02/06/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(9,1500.0,sdf.parse("29/06/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(10,1200.0,sdf.parse("30/06/2022"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(11,700.0,sdf.parse("30/06/2021"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        listVed.add(new Venda(11,1000.0,sdf.parse("30/06/2021"),Finalizadora.CartaoCredito));
        
        System.out.println("Escolha o mês (somente numeros): ");
        int mesEsc = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Escolha o ano (somente numeros): ");
        int anoEsc = sc.nextInt();  

        System.out.println("Total de vendas para o período: " +  calculaValorVendasPorData(mesEsc,anoEsc));
    }
    private static float calculaValorVendasPorData(int mesEsc, int anoEsc){
        float soma = 0.0;
         for(Venda v : vendas) {
            if(/*regra para verificar se a venda v esta dentro do rage de data*/){
                soma += v.getValor();
            }
        }
        return soma;
    }


}
```

e a sua classe venda:

```java
public class Venda {

    private Integer id; 
    private Double valor;
    private Date dataCompra;
    private Finalizadora tipoCompra; 
    
    private List<Venda> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    
    public Venda () {
        
    }

    public Venda(Integer id, Double valor, Date dataCompra, Finalizadora tipoCompra) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.dataCompra = dataCompra;
        this.tipoCompra = tipoCompra;
    }
    
    public Double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public Date getDataCompra() {
        return dataCompra;
    }

    public void setDataCompra(Date dataCompra) {
        this.dataCompra = dataCompra;
    }

    public Finalizadora getTipoCompra() {
        return tipoCompra;
    }

    public void setTipoCompra(Finalizadora tipoCompra) {
        this.tipoCompra = tipoCompra;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
  
    
    public Status verStatus(Date dataCompra) {
        long diff = new Date().getTime() - dataCompra.getTime();
        diff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Status st;
        if(diff <= 30) {
             st = Status.ATIVO;
        }
        else if (diff >= 31 && diff <= 90) {
            st = Status.PRE_INATIVO;
        }
        else {
            st = Status.INATIVO;
        }
        
        return st;
        
    }
    
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dados da Venda \n" +  
                " valor:  " + valor + 
                ", Data:  " + sdf.format(dataCompra) + 
                ", Forma de pagamento: " + tipoCompra;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Olá, fiz como você orientou ele ate funciona, porém o que esta acontecendo é seguinte, quando coloco o IF para filtrar a data ele me retorna 0, testando aqui percebi que, ou ele não entra no IF ou ele não entra no FOR para percorre a lista. Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.